# unix shell scripting for moving files sequentially with file names as fixed increment into directories

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have large number of directories basically as increments of a time step say 0.00125. I want to copy the time directories into 8 directories sequentially i.e the algorithm I can think of is

```
delta_time = 0.00125
    if directory_name = 0.00125 then mv 0.00125/ to main_dir1
    if directory_name = 0.0025  then mv 0.00250/ to main_dir2
    if directory_name = 0.00375 then mv 0.00375/ to main_dir3
    .
    .
    .
    if directory_name = 0.01    then mv 0.01/ to main_dir8
    if directory_name = 0.01125 then mv 0.01125/ to main_dir1 (again)
    if directory_name = 0.0125  then mv 0.0125/  to main_dir2     
    .
    .
    .
    .
    if directory_name = 0.02    then mv 0.02/ to main_dir8
    .
    .
    so on
```

The time directories are large in number (around 200 directories) so Im thinking of writing a bash script. Im relatively new to bash scripting but still cant think of a logic to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just want to do modular arithmetic on the directory names, with the exception that for even multiples of 8 you want to use 8 instead of 0. So:

```
#!/bin/sh

increment="0.00125"
maxdir=8
for directory_name in 0.*
do
    if [ -d "$directory_name" ]
    then
        TARGET_DIR_NUM=$(echo "($directory_name / $increment) % $maxdir" | bc)
        if [ $TARGET_DIR_NUM -eq 0 ]
        then
            TARGET_DIR_NUM=$maxdir
        fi 
        echo mv $directory_name main_dir${TARGET_DIR_NUM}
    fi 
done
```

should do the trick.

Comment: So Cool! Okay, now this works with moving files. Just thinking if I have to copy then this wouldn't work since the loop will be within the first 8 directories since I leave a copy. That would be a bit more efficient! any suggested tweaks to the above code?